# Fancybox Multiple Galleries Issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox, fancybox-2

I am trying to do the same thing as done in this Fancybox example here: http://jsfiddle.net/jekAe/

When I do it it keeps opening up the second gallery for all links.  Here's what I have:

My JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var images = {
    1: [
        {
            href : 'images/1.jpg',                
        },
        {
            href : 'images/2.jpg',                
        },
        {
            href : 'images/3.jpg',                
        },
        {
            href : 'images/4.jpg',                
        },
        {
            href : 'images/5.jpg',                
        }
    ],
    2: [
        {
            href : 'images/6.jpg',                
        },
        {
            href : 'images/7.jpg',                
        },
        {
            href : 'images/8.jpg',                
        },
        {
            href : 'images/9.jpg',                
        },
        {
            href : 'images/10.jpg',                
        }
    ],
    3: [
        {
            href : 'images/11.jpg',                
        },
        {
            href : 'images/12.jpg',                
        },
        {
            href : 'images/13.jpg',                
        }
    ]
};

$(".open_fancybox").click(function() {
    $.fancybox.open(images[ $(this).index() + 1], {
        padding : 0
    });

    return false;
});
});
```

My HTML:

```
<a class="open_fancybox" href="images/1.jpg"><img src="images/services-bg-01.jpg" alt="" width="290" height="140" class="services-bg" /></a>
<a class="open_fancybox" href="images/6.jpg"><img src="images/services-bg-02.jpg" alt="" width="290" height="140" class="services-bg" /></a>
<a class="open_fancybox" href="images/11.jpg"><img src="images/services-bg-03.jpg" alt="" width="290" height="140" class="services-bg" /></a>
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here.  I know very little jQuery and from the sample code on jsfiddle I thought I could do the exact same thing with 3 galleries but it's not working out that way.

No matter which link I click it always opens up the second gallery.

Answer (score 1):

I created a fiddle of your problem using the code you included but the images in the example fiddle- It appears to work as you want it to.

http://jsfiddle.net/YqLhw/

I believe the problem actually lies in code that you have not included

```
<a class="open_fancybox" href="images/1.jpg"><img src="images/services-bg-01.jpg" alt="" width="290" height="140" class="services-bg" /></a>
<a class="open_fancybox" href="images/6.jpg"><img src="images/services-bg-02.jpg" alt="" width="290" height="140" class="services-bg" /></a>
<a class="open_fancybox" href="images/11.jpg"><img src="images/services-bg-03.jpg" alt="" width="290" height="140" class="services-bg" /></a>
```

Works well but if the `<a>` tags are wrapped in for example `<li>` tags then the indexing breaks.

```
<li><a class="open_fancybox" href="images/1.jpg"><img src="images/services-bg-01.jpg" alt="" width="290" height="140" class="services-bg" /></a></li>
<li><a class="open_fancybox" href="images/6.jpg"><img src="images/services-bg-02.jpg" alt="" width="290" height="140" class="services-bg" /></a></li>
<li><a class="open_fancybox" href="images/11.jpg"><img src="images/services-bg-03.jpg" alt="" width="290" height="140" class="services-bg" /></a></li>
```

What I assume is happening is that

```
$(".open_fancybox").click(function() {
$.fancybox.open(images[ $(this).index() + 1], {
```

Is indexing based on the number of `<a>` tags in each individual `<li>` and then assigning each an index of 1.

My initial solution was to move the `.open_fancybox` class from the `<a>` to the parent `<li>` elements.

I later found that that in my implementation this meant that other `<li>` elements without my `.open_fancybox` class were included in the indexing, creating more problems.

I decided to simply change the automatic `$(this).index()` to `$(this).data("galnum")` and manually set `data-galnum=#` for each linked gallery element. My final code looks a bit like this:

```
<li class="open_fancybox" data-galnum="1"><a href="images/1.jpg"><img src="images/services-bg-01.jpg" alt="" width="290" height="140" class="services-bg" /></a></li>
<li class="open_fancybox" data-galnum="2"><a href="images/6.jpg"><img src="images/services-bg-02.jpg" alt="" width="290" height="140" class="services-bg" /></a></li>
<li class="open_fancybox" data-galnum="3"><a href="images/11.jpg"><img src="images/services-bg-03.jpg" alt="" width="290" height="140" class="services-bg" /></a></li>
```

I chose to keep the `.open_fancybox` class on the `<li>` elements though that is not necessary.
This solution hinges upon the idea that you wrapped the `<a>`'s but didn't include it here. If you didn't I'm sorry I cant help, I thought I'd put this here in case ( Or for others who made the same mistake as I did). I have next to no understanding of Javascript/JQuery so I was proud to figure this out. I'm pretty sure there are a bunch of other ways to deal with this issue; this solution is the simplest for me and works in my implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Probably not the best way to do this but I kind of did what the person above recommended.  Here's what I did:

```
$(".open_fancybox1").click(function() {
    $.fancybox.open(images[ $(this).index() + 0], {
        padding : 0
    });

    return false;
});
$(".open_fancybox2").click(function() {
    $.fancybox.open(images[ $(this).index() + 1], {
        padding : 0
    });

    return false;
});
$(".open_fancybox3").click(function() {
    $.fancybox.open(images[ $(this).index() + 2], {
        padding : 0
    });

    return false;
});

<a class="open_fancybox1" href="images/1.jpg"><img src="images/services-bg-01.jpg" alt="" width="290" height="140" class="services-bg" /></a>
<a class="open_fancybox2" href="images/6.jpg"><img src="images/services-bg-02.jpg" alt="" width="290" height="140" class="services-bg" /></a>
<a class="open_fancybox3" href="images/11.jpg"><img src="images/services-bg-03.jpg" alt="" width="290" height="140" class="services-bg" /></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you don't need to declare fancybox 3 times as suggested : what if you decide to add more galleries? you wouldn't like to add a new script every time, would you?

Using `.each()` can save you the trip :

```
$(".open_fancybox").each(function (i) {
    $(this).on("click", function () {
        $.fancybox.open(images[i + 1], {
            padding: 0
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

See **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/72k5d/)**

Answer (score -1):

you need to give each image a separate/unique class and then declare fancybox 3 times, one for each new class.